# Need function the gives DateTime for first day of week given the day number for first day of week

Tags: sql-server

For many, first day of work week is Monday, but lets say its a different day, say Wednesday.

Can you help me create a function (SQL Server 2012) that returns the date for the fist day in:

1. Current Week
2. Next Week
3. Last Week

So a function where we give a date, Type(Current, Next, Last), FirstDay(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) and would return a datetime of first day of Current or next or Last day of week depending on type.

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStartofWeek]
(
    @FirstDay int,
    @type VARCHAR(10),
    @day DATETime
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: The 1900 date system has a behavior where `MOD(<date>, 7)` is equal to the weekday where Sunday is zero. If you want Wednesday to be zero, add 4 to *<date>*. `MOD` wasn't introduced until SQL 2014 but can easily be imitated with `SELECT CONVERT(int, getdate()) - 7 * (CONVERT(int, getdate()) / 7)`. The rest of your question is just addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will give you the dates you are looking for:

```
create function [dbo].[GetStartofWeek] 
(
    @firstDay int, 
    @type varchar(10), 
    @day date
) 
returns date as
begin

-- use datediff/dateadd to get the date of sunday for the week of the given @day (-1 casts as Sunday 1899-12-31)
declare @sundayOfWeek date = dateadd(week, datediff(week, -1, @day), -1)

-- @firstDay is 0 to 6, 0 representing Sunday
declare @firstDayOfWeek date = dateadd(day, @firstDay, @sundayOfWeek)

-- add or subtract a week if necessary
set @type = upper(@type)

if @type = 'LAST'
    set @firstDayOfWeek = dateadd(week, -1, @firstDayOfWeek)
else if @type = 'NEXT'
    set @firstDayOfWeek = dateadd(week, 1, @firstDayOfWeek)

return @firstDayOfWeek
end
go
```

Tested with the following inputs:

```
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](0, 'Last',    '2014-12-14')   -- 2014-12-07   
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](3, 'Last',    '2014-12-14')   -- 2014-12-10   
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](6, 'Last',    '2014-12-14')   -- 2014-12-13   
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](0, 'Current', '2014-12-17')   -- 2014-12-14   
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](3, 'Current', '2014-12-17')   -- 2014-12-17
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](6, 'Current', '2014-12-17')   -- 2014-12-20
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](0, 'Next',    '2014-12-20')   -- 2014-12-21
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](3, 'Next',    '2014-12-20')   -- 2014-12-24
select [dbo].[GetStartofWeek](6, 'Next',    '2014-12-20')   -- 2014-12-27
```

One suggestion would be to use a week offset instead of 'Last'/'Current'/'Next', which is a bit cleaner and more flexible:

```
alter function [dbo].[GetStartofWeek] 
(
    @firstDay int, 
    @weekOffset int, 
    @day date
) 
returns date as
begin

-- use datediff/dateadd to get the date of sunday for the week of the given @day (-1 casts as Sunday 1899-12-31)
declare @sundayOfWeek date = dateadd(week, datediff(week, -1, @day), -1)

-- @firstDay is 0 to 6, 0 representing Sunday
declare @firstDayOfWeek date = dateadd(day, @firstDay, @sundayOfWeek)

-- add or subtract weeks if necessary
if @weekOffset <> 0
begin
    set @firstDayOfWeek = dateadd(week, @weekOffset, @firstDayOfWeek)
end

return @firstDayOfWeek
end
go
```